# Error using Python BigQuery API with user authentication

Tags: google-bigquery, google-authentication

**I'm getting an error when querying BigQuery from Python using end-user authentication**

It works successfully *with service account authentication*, but fails with *end-user authentication*.
I am essentially following these instructions https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user

**The error message is:**
`ProjectId and DatasetId must be non-empty`

I am stumped. Using service account authentication returns the expected data, so it appears to be an authentication related issue, but the authentication step appears to be successful.

**Details**

```
from google_auth_oauthlib import flow
from google.cloud import bigquery

appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
    "client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"])
appflow.run_local_server()
credentials = appflow.credentials

client = bigquery.Client(project='MyProject', credentials=credentials)
query_string = """SELECT name, SUM(number) as total
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
WHERE name = 'William'
GROUP BY name;
"""
query_job = client.query(query_string)

for row in query_job.result(): 
    print("{}: {}".format(row["name"], row["total"]))
```

gives the following errors:

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\test\bqtest3.py", line 15, in <module>
    query_job = client.query(query_string)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 3331, in query
    return _job_helpers.query_jobs_insert(
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_job_helpers.py", line 114, in query_jobs_insert
    future = do_query()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\_job_helpers.py", line 91, in do_query
    query_job._begin(retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\job\query.py", line 1298, in _begin
    super(QueryJob, self)._begin(client=client, retry=retry, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\job\base.py", line 510, in _begin
    api_response = client._call_api(
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 756, in _call_api
    return call()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 283, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 190, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\_http\__init__.py", line 494, in api_request
    raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/MyProject/jobs?prettyPrint=false: ProjectId and DatasetId must be non-empty

Location: None
Job ID: 9eba1ce9-971a-4495-825a-728aed28fc98
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add python env to the script like below(first line).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from google_auth_oauthlib import flow
from google.cloud import bigquery

appflow = flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("client_secrets.json", scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"])
appflow.run_local_server()
credentials = appflow.credentials

client = bigquery.Client(project='MyProject', credentials=credentials)
query_job = client.query(
    """
    SELECT name, SUM(number) as total
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
    WHERE name = 'William'
    GROUP BY name;
    """
)

for row in query_job.result(): 
    print("{}: {}".format(row["name"], row["total"]))
```